# Why does the space bar do page down in browsers

Tags: interface, usability-study, browser, space-bar

Why is the <kbd>space</kbd> bar doing a page down in some viewer apps, especially browsers and PDF readers?

For me this seems to be a bit counter-intuitive, and also this behaviour affects games and other interactive HTML5 apps, because if you map some action to the space bar it might also scroll down the page, which is not what you want. Also the arrow keys, page down button and the mouse scrollwheel are usually enough options to scroll down the page.

Are there any historical or usability reasons for this behaviour?

Comment: It's also a usability issue for non-full-screen videos. Space is frequently used to pause/play videos; I'm always scrolling down youtube thanks to this.

Comment: I did not even know that.

Comment: Me neither ! - and I've been using a browser since Netscape Navigator 1.0.  The spacebar is for adding spaces in my mental model of the world...

Comment: None of all that gobbledegook above means anything. Every time I hit the spacebar in Notability, it takes me backwards to a list of my documents. No one at Apple Care or elsewhere knows how to solve the problem. So my answer here is just as good (or bad) as all those above, which also didn't help. I believe there is no solution for this.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The historical reason is that that's what the spacebar does in [more](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?more), the lowest common demoninator (and probably oldest) of text pagers. In `more`, it makes sense to map the largest key on the keyboard to the most common action: show the next page.

In the glory days of `more`, you couldn't count on mouse scrollwheels, page down buttons, or sometimes even arrow keys. `more` doesn't even have a "page up" feature (you can't go back).

Although in the text-based world `more` has mostly been replaced with more powerful pagers like [less](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?less) (which *can* move backward), that spacebar convention remains, and has even migrated to the GUI world.

Comment: i think in this case it's size and position contributes to the choice of this functionality, like it does with stop and play on youtube

Comment: Do you _guess_ the historical reason or do you _know_ it? Could you provide some evidence?

Comment: "Press space to continue" was a very common way to move through an app in the pre-GUI home computing days of the 1980s, probably because it was the biggest button. Some apps implemented "Press any key to continue". This was slightly risky, as it didn't really mean "any" key, pressing escape or break would probably exit the programme, and it's alleged that some people couldn't find the "any" key.

Comment: @phresnel The request for evidence is not unreasonable, but do remember that some of us are old enough that our programming days predate the PC and we've *lived* this 'spacebar for page down' time. There are probably many things not being written down (to be *evidence* later) because they're so obvious. For me, Celada's answer is that obvious. :)

Comment: @Cheeseminer: Alternatively, the formulation could be changed to no longer represent a fact. If something cannot be proven then it can at most be a claim. There's definitely a correlation, however, obviousness is the enemey of the truth. Example: To me it is obvious that the earth is flat and that the sun sets and rises around our planet. Air is immaterial, because I cannot hold it. And there is no mass market for computers, so probably you are working at IBM and currently computing the diameter of the earth disk.

Comment: I hope you don't mind my edit: Relaxed it from fact to guess.

Comment: Other examples backing this hypothesis: slash shortcut for find in Firefox (from vi), ctrl+a / ctrl+e as Home and End on MacOs (from emacs)... I guess programmers (which are the first users of these programs) enable shortcuts compliant with their previous habits.

Comment: @phresnel I think the hard evidence you are looking for simply doesn't exist. This behavior of the space bar organically took root over time and eventually became tradition. It's often hard to pinpoint a specific decision; the best you might be able to do is ask [Daniel Halbert, author of `more`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/More_(command)) why he chose the spacebar, and even that relies on the presumption that `more` drove that choice. Sometimes the best we can do is theorize and present evidence that *supports* our theories.

Comment: @phresnel (continued) ... This sort of thing comes up a lot in UI/UX design. Why is the minimize button on the top right? Why do pixel-based Windows dialogs use a [6 pixel button spacing and 12 pixel borders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb226787(v=vs.85).aspx) (and similarly, why are DLUs based on 8-point MS Sans Serif)? Why is does Ctrl+V mean paste (it was chosen by Xerox Parc back in Alto days but good luck finding a rationale)? At some point, somebody made a decision, possibly for completely arbitrary reasons, and it stuck.

Comment: @Jason C: Yeah, of course, I do not disagree with all the comments. But this confirms that it should not be represented as a fact, but as a guess or something that is probable.

Comment: @phresnel: Not really, in human communication and the english language indicative mood can be used to express opinions ("You look gorgeous!") or things one believes to be true. SE is *not* a encyclopedia, but a Q&A network where *humans* give answers. Any answer is a claim, no matter the mood in which it is formulated. Citing any sources - which will be dubious at best here at UX - won't change that. Or do you wish that on mathematics SE users would answer the question "What is 1+1" with "I, and person x & y, claim that the answer is 2"? That would just ruin efficient communication.

Comment: Right, “space” moves a page forward and “b” moves a page back. Sadly, the latter is more forgotten… I have to configure Opera to allow it all the time. But it's important!

Answer (score 30):

The spacebar is the largest key of your keyboard, and is consequently the easiest one to **interact** with. For that reason, apps tend to use the spacebar for:

- a *simple* action: where no input, precision or direction is involved.
- a *repeated* action: the spacebar is the easiest to press several times in a row.
- a *"forgivable"* action: if you accidentally press it, it's easily undoable.

For example, a media player's primary action is to toggle Play and Pause. It's simple (a yes/no toggle), it's repeated (with intervals), and it's forgivable (it's a toggle after all).

A browser primary action is to **scroll** because the web is still about reading content. It's simple (just go down), it's repeated (you scroll step by step), and it's forgivable (you can use your mouse or your arrows or even shift+space to go back).

Comment: An alternate take is: in GUIs, a button click could be executed using the Spacebar (provided the button was the active item), and since play/record/pause in Windows 3's sndrec.exe/mplayer.exe (or even earlier) were, well, buttons, it became customary for users to hit the spacebar. I can't remember having used the spacebar as play/pause keys in DOS applications like Autodesk Animator..

Comment: @jørgensen in AA didn't space show/hide the toolbar?

Comment: I had never thought of shift+space.

Comment: Another plus of the spacebar here is it's the closest key to you; if you are, say, sitting back in your chair to read a long document, the large size and close proximity of the spacebar make it one of the least awkward keys to press in that situation. And, when you are in typing position, it's pretty much the only key that is constantly under a finger -- you don't really use your thumbs for any other keys that often. It's a very low effort key to press overall (page down, on the other hand, is usually a bit out of the way, and can vary greatly between keyboards).

Comment: But isn't it a usability concern that the space button mmean completely different things inside (consumer) apps? Isn't it a bad thing that it's context can change during browsing as well (though it's not that annoying than pushing the backspace button while not inside a form)?

Comment: @SztupY IMHO, since for the most part it means one of those two things (rather than constantly varying wildly from app to app), I'd argue that those two uses are intuitive, and anything outside is potentially confusing -- but that's just me! But it does get annoying in browsers sometimes (although not quite as annoying as Chrome using the backspace key to mean "back"; meaning that if you accidentally lose focus while deleting text, you unrecoverably lose your progress). Really what's important is that when the context *does* change, it's not a sudden surprise to the user.

Comment: @JasonC it's not just Chrome using backspace as back, but it's also quite common (and annoying). The rest does make sense, yeah

Comment: In Opera, when you've reached the end of the page and press space again, it will navigate to the next page - which is not always forgivable.

Comment: @SztupY Correct; it enabled an unblocked view of the current image (which in browsers today is the F11 key). BTW, Autodesk Animator's source is now open and on github.

Comment: @jørgensen: OMG, it was one of my favourite programs, didn't knew I could actually look at it's source!

Comment: But what about a media player inside of a web browser?  I think the default action of the spacebar when viewing, say, a YouTube video, should be to pause/play.  Except that's not what the video player on YouTube does.  On YT, and most other sites where a video is playing, the spacebar scrolls a page down.  We shouldn't get locked into a historical mindset.  The behavior of the spacebar in any application should be context-dependent.  So if a video is playing in a region on a page, and the video is the primary element, then the spacebar should pause/play the video.

Answer (score 20):

I don't have any evidence that this is the reason the spacebar is used for page down, but back in the day when IBM was setting PC design standards (that still heavily influence the design today), the original [IBM AT 84-key keyboard](http://www.pcguide.com/ref/kb/layout/stdAT84-c.html) from 1981 (IIRC) did not have page up/down or dedicated arrow keys (they shared the number pad):

[image]

The standard [101-key keyboard](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/globalization/topics/keyboards/physical.html) didn't come on the scene until 3-ish years later. There were competitors to IBM too, and strange alternatives all over the place, e.g. the [MIT Space Cadet](http://home.comcast.net/~mmcm/kbd/SpaceCadet.html), which has no page up/down, and has the hand symbols that vaguely resemble arrows:

[image]

From the link above re: the hand keys (emphasis mine):

> Thumbs- up, down, left, and right keys. *It was never quite clear
>   whether these were for answering yes/no questions or for navigation.
>   In the groups that used this keyboard, there was a cultural aversion
>   to arrow keys.* To be honest, I'm not sure why any more.

The rapid development of new (and sometimes competing) technologies and interfaces at the time probably led to years of page up/down and arrows being an unreliable / inconsistent source of interaction (and standardization was not as wide-spread at the time), but one key all these keyboards had in common was the spacebar; it has always been around and unchanged.

Also, the mouse didn't really fall into general consumer use until around the same time as the 101-key keyboard; with the first Mac's in 1984, and it raised a lot of eyebrows. It was a while before the mouse was as much of a staple as it is today (and even today a mouse is still a bit of an option; you are far more likely to find a computer with no mouse than with no keyboard).

I imagine that this combined with the usage points jgthms brings up in his answer are the reasons that programs like `more` (mentioned in Celada's answer) and others used the spacebar so heavily -- [`more`, for example, was written in 1978](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/More_%28command%29#History), well before any truly meaningful standardization of extra keyboard keys. Over time, it probably just stuck.

Comment: Back in 1978 the vt100 would have been the hot new thing: http://www.computerhistory.org/revolution/input-output/14/349/1849 ... I used one for years.

Comment: Wow, it even has a built-in Like button

Comment: My first computer didn't even have up and down arrows, let alone page up and page down. http://www.cs.grinnell.edu/drupal6/sites/default/files/museum/140_0.jpg

Comment: The keyboard on the [Alto](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/98287-from-punchcards-to-ipads-the-history-of-input-devices/3) (1973) was another pre-AT one without navigation keys.

Comment: @user894763 And the influence of the VT100 still reaches us today; e.g. pretty much any terminal emulator.

Comment: Ah, the `rub out` key... haven't seen that one in *years*!

Comment: It's also worth noting that keyboard design was generally inspired by typewriter layout, and typewriters had no concept of page up/down or cursor navigation - these were all brand new concepts back then (somewhat like the concept of interactive zoom on touch screens in recent years, with UI now converging on pinch-zoom).

Answer (score 13):

From a pure source code perspective, "why" may be hard to answer.

In the latest [WebKit](http://nightly.webkit.org/), there is no commentary (neither the GTK implementation nor the EFL one):

```
 case VK_SPACE:
    granularity = WebCore::ScrollByPage;
    if (keyEvent.shiftKey())
        direction = WebCore::ScrollUp;
    else
        direction = WebCore::ScrollDown;
    break;
```

Rewind the clock back to [NCSA Mosaic](https://github.com/alandipert/ncsa-mosaic), no commentary:

```
  case XK_space:
      XtVaGetValues (win->scrolled_win, XmNverticalScrollBar,
                     (long)(&sb), NULL);
      if (sb && XtIsManaged (sb)) {
          XtCallActionProc (sb, "PageDownOrRight", event, params, 1);
      }
      break;
```

Go back further to [Nexus (nee WorldWideWeb)](http://browsers.evolt.org/browsers/archive/worldwideweb/NeXT/) circa 1992, where there was no keyboard navigation: [navigation was done with the mouse](http://www.w3.org/People/Berners-Lee/WorldWideWeb.html).

[WWWLineMode](http://browsers.evolt.org/archive/worldwideweb/NeXT/WWWLineMode_0.11a.tar.gz) circa 1991 did not map space to anything.  In `WWW/LineMode/Implementation/www.c`, the function `User_Selection` has no reference to space bar.  However, it does map new line, that is the `ENTER` key to next page!

Based on this review, the functionality was introduced in Mosaic.  But, I could not find the source for Erwise or ViolaWWW, so maybe there.

Given this, the fact that Mosaic was popular on Windows, and Windows used an IBM AT keyboard, the explanation @JasonC provided seems most likely to me.

Comment: +1 While it cannot answer the question, it's great that this actually shows that this behaviour was there from almost the beginning of browsers (and not coined in IE or Netscape).

Comment: @SztupY: Yep, indeed. And notice that space bar in Mosaic went page down *or right*. To my knowledge, space bar never went right anywhere else.

Answer (score 4):

> For me this seems to be a bit counter-intuitive, and also this
>   behaviour affects games and other interactive HTML5 apps, because if
>   you map some action to the space bar it might also scroll down the
>   page, which is not what you want.

The main question about historical background has been covered by other answers, but I thought it would be worth pointing this out. (This would probably be a better fit as a comment, but my lack of reputation points prevents me from commenting.)

Most well-designed pages, games or apps will account for this issue by preventing the default behavior of certain keys (for example, using JavaScript's event.preventDefault()) when the game or app has focus. Focus is most often gained by a page component when a user has clicked/touched/navigated to via tab the component. It can also be assigned programatically. Of course, if you have control over the entire page itself, you could prevent the default behavior of the space bar on the entire page, not just for the app or game.